# Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly when trying to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
    I have WAMP server version 2.2. Previously, MySQL Server running normally. 
    I don't know why when I tried to start, it cannot start anymore. 
    Here are the content of MySQL.log:

    140502 21:04:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    140502 21:04:47 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    140502 21:04:47  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    140502 21:04:48 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
    140502 21:04:48 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
    140502 21:04:48 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
    140502 21:04:48 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
    140502 21:04:48 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
    140502 21:04:48 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
    140502 21:04:48 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
    140502 21:04:48 [ERROR] Aborting

    140502 21:04:48  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
    140502 21:04:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
    140502 21:04:49 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

    I had already tried to reinstall WAMP server but appear the same error.


    Can someone help me, please...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Irhandi Ferianto! What did you tried to solve it? Did you do any change in the computer? Can you reverse those changes?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the port is trying to be opened by another storage engine than InnoDB. Refer to this article for some commands that can help you identify what's happening.

For instance, `netstat -an | findstr "3306"`

[danielschneller.com/2007/10/cant-start-server-bind-on-tcpip-port-no.html](http://www.danielschneller.com/2007/10/cant-start-server-bind-on-tcpip-port-no.html)

Comment: Better use `netstat -ano | findstr "3306"`. This command will show process ID in the right column, so you can easy find it in the task manager and kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Something is already working on that port. In administrator CMD console write

```
netstat -abn
```

and find port 3306, then you will know what is blocking the port (what is already running on it and blocks your mysql).

If that doesnt help you then check my.ini settings
In that file search for

```
socket = /something
```

and change that to

```
socket = c:/something
```

Comment: I have seen the output of netstat -abn. But port 3306 exactly used by [mysqld.exe]

Comment: So its already working on that port. In Windows Task Manager go to Services tab, and search for mysql or something similar in name. You will find it with Status => Running   you may stop it and then start it by wamp ways. It should work.

But before you can always try to connect to the database (`heidisql` for windows for example) to check if database is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

setting file `my.ini` : 
    innodb_flush_method=normal

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows 7 32-bit.

### Cause

Some filenames are reserved by Windows, such as `${machinename}.pid`, `${machinename}.err`, etc.

MySQL uses some of these filenames by default.

### Solution

After the installation is complete, during the configuration phase, there's an Advanced option using which you can change these filenames. You can change the log file names but not the pid file name.

You need to step through the configuration wizard to the "starting service" step, and then it will throw an error/warning message.  Leave the wizard paused (do not stop/cancel the wizard).

By now, your `my.ini` file has been created. You can add the following variable

```
pid_file=/path/to/pid/file.pid
```

Then go to Windows Services and start the service.

**N.B. DO NOT STOP/CANCEL THE WIZARD.**

Once the service is started, the wizard will continue, and will configure MySQL properly.